# Absolute Path to Relative with Applicatin Context Change

Tags: javascript, url, velocity

I'm trying to change absolute paths into relatives at my current application. I apply that procedure:

Before:

```
var path = '$link.getContextPath()/elma/dino';
```

After:

```
var path = 'elma/dino';
```

and it works. However I have that piece of code:

```
var contextURL = '$link.getContextURL()';
var contexPath = '$link.getContextPath()';
var rootPath = contextURL.replace(contexPath , '');
var path = rootPath + '/auro/lemma';
```

At this code, application context is changed. So, the procedure that I've applied below is not applicable for this case.

How can I convert that path variable which holds an absolute path into a relative one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the request to:

```
/auro/lemma
```

works for given aim.